# Query Regarding Alexa Echo Skills

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Is it possible for me to disable or delete the inbuilt Alexa Echo's skills so that only my added skills are operational?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take a look at reference link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Could you share an example of what you are trying to achieve? You can invoke your skill and perform actions around it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable a skill in your echo device please follow these steps:

-Press the Down arrow until “Amazon Alexa” is highlighted.

-Press Ok.

-The Settings: Amazon Alexa Status screen displays.

-Press the Down arrow until “Disable Alexa” is highlighted.